# Get svn repository details

Tags: svn, command-line

I just checked out an SVN repository a while ago -- is there any way I can get the details of where I checked it out from by running an SVN command locally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `svn info` in that directory.
Full info here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html